# How to swap an array string globally, considering an element is "**"

Tags: javascript, arrays, str-replace

normally using the 
`arr.replace(/xxx/g, "yyy")`
would work, but when the original string is `"***"`,a problem occurs where the /* turns the code into a comment.
How do I keep the "***" while being able to replace it 
Input

> `let arr = ["***"]`

```
arr.replace(/***/g, "yyy")
```

Output

> `let arr = ["yyy"]`

this is what is supposed to happen

Comment: Make a minimal snippet and show your input and expected output, show it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Is that Javascript ? And if the '**' is a problem because of multiline comment, there's always the option of using a \ to escape the '*'. And beside, in regexp, the valid pattern to match 3 characters would be `.{3}` (`***` is not a valid regexp, perhaps a glob pattern ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply escape your `*` using `\` and matching exactly 3 characters should be done using `{count}`. And for working with this array you can use `.map()` to create a copy containing the replaced strings.

```js
function replacer(str) {
  return str.replace(/\*{3}/g, "yyy");
}

let arr = ["***"];

let arr2 = arr.map(str => replacer(str));
console.log(arr2);
```